# 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77AAB960)

Tags: c

The code bellow sometimes throws exceptions similar to:

Exception thrown at 0x779CC19E (ntdll.dll) in Matriks.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000001D.

I'm new to C and just learned to use pointers. Any tips ? Are there other problems in my code that are worth criticizing ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

main()
{
    int *Matrix_01, *Matrix_02;
    int a, b, i, n,valid=1;
    srand(time(0));
    do 
    {
        printf("Insert number of rows: ");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        printf("Insert number of columns: ");
        scanf("%d", &b);
        if (a >= 0 && b >= 0)
            valid = 0;
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid input!");
            system("pause>null & cls");
        }
    } while (valid == 1);

    Matrix_01 = (int *)malloc(a * b * sizeof(int));
    Matrix_02 = (int *)malloc(a * b * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
        for (n = 0; n < b; n++)
        {
            Matrix_01[a*i + n] = rand() % 50;
            Matrix_02[a*i + n] = rand() % 50;
        }
    printf("\nFirst Matrix:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (n = 0; n < b; n++)
        {
            printf("%4d", Matrix_01[a*i + n]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nSecond Matrix:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (n = 0; n < b; n++)
        {
            printf("%4d", Matrix_02[a*i + n]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nAddition:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (n = 0; n < b; n++)
        {
            printf("%4d", Matrix_01[a*i + n]+Matrix_02[a*i + n]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nSubtraction:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (n = 0; n < b; n++)
        {
            printf("%4d", Matrix_01[a*i + n] - Matrix_02[a*i + n]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause>null");
}
```

Comment: Why are you changing your code on the fly? Please post the exact code which is generating the exact error, and not some "tweaked" one.

Comment: I don't have any problems to run this, write your input numbers and your host envirnoment

Comment: `if (a >= 0 && b >= 0)` that's not a good test. You don't want either a or b to be 0

Comment: index is wrong: `a*i + n` => `b*i + n`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The whole `valid` thing seem to be inverted

Comment: no, `valid==1` is set at start. Loop exits when `valid==0` (which probably means: no need to validate anymore). I agree this is misleading

Comment: By allowing `a` and `b` to be zero, you run the risk of running `malloc(0)`. What do you think happens when you try to dereference or use a pointer created by that?

Comment: regarding: `main()`  This results in a warning from the compiler.  In days gone by, a missing return type would default to `int` but not today.  Suggest: `int main( void )`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  Regarding: `srand(time(0));`  This results in some 'conversion' warnings from the compiler.  Suggest: `srand( (unsigned int)time( NULL ) );`

Comment: OT:  regarding this kind of statement: `Matrix_01 = (int *)malloc(a * b * sizeof(int));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest removing the cast.  2) when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()`, `calloc()`, and/or `realloc()` always check (!=NULL) the returned value.  If not successful, then call `perror( "malloc failed" );` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heap is corrupt in that case means that you wrote out of the valid allocated zones.

Check the min & max values of your index:

- `i` ranges from `0` to `a-1`
- `n` ranges from `0` to `b-1`

So `a*i + n` ranges from `0` to `a*(a+1) + b`. So it doesn't match the matrix dimensions. If `a` is bigger than `b` the memory will get corrupted.

You need to replace this by `b*i + n` (which ranges from `0` to `b*(a-1) + b` => `a*b`

You also want to avoid to allow that `a` or `b` is zero when reading the input. Actually, it's better to check if `scanf` succeeded in scanning one value by checking the return code *then* check if values are greater than zero (but not equal) 
Or use 2D matrixes (or compute pointers on rows once to avoid those computations)